# Single Sign On redirects to different url after successful login

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on

I am new to single sign on concept.I have an issue with the url.The requirement is that ,let us say my single sign on application has url "http://www.mysso.com" , once entering the URL ,it will prompt for username and password.After entering username and password and clicked login we call a service  from another application in different server .After it is executed the home page of required application is opened.But the URL changes to "http://www.myapplicationurl.com".The code is given below :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void homePage(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("MY_USER_ID",
            httpSessionBean.getMyUID(request));

    cookie.setDomain(".mydomain.com");
    cookie.setMaxAge(10);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    response.addCookie(cookie);

    httpSessionBean.removeUser(request);

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myProperties.properties"));

    response.sendRedirect("http://www.myapplicationurl.mydomain.com");
}
```

Now i want the URL to remain as same as the SSO URL and not the myapplicationurl.com. How do i achieve it.Kindly let me know how it can be implemented in java

Answer (score 0):

response.sendRedirect("http://www.myapplicationurl.mydomain.com");

this is the code line that redirects to myapplicationurl.com remove this line and you will not be redirected.

Comment: but that is the url in which i have my other application running in a server.The one which is supposed to open after single sign on